# I want vba to find a value greater than 0 in one matrix and copy it into another matrix in the cell that has a yellow background

Tags: vba, excel, matrix, copy, find

Matrix 1 and Matrix 2. Matrix 2 contains values grater than 0 and Matrix 1 contains yellow cells. I now want a code that Looks for the first value greater than 0 in Matrix 2, substracts one from the found cell value, goes one to the left, copies the test "Task 1" and pastes it into the first yellow cell it finds in Matrix 1.

It is Kind of a schedule that distributes Tasks into my calendar, where the yellow fields of my calendar represent the times that are dedicated to work.

[image: The Excel sheet]

My Approach:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim z As Integer



Do
'my loop'
For Each cell In Range("b1:b3")
cell.Value = z
'Searching one Matrix by values greater than 0'
If cell.Value > "0" Then
 'reducing cell value by one'
    cell.Value = cell.Value - 1





' The following line is  going one to the left where the corresponding text is and '
'copying it to another cell - Range("k17") is the place where it is copied to.' 
'I want however that it is being copied into a yellow cell. That means '
 'using a code that searches another Matrix, like Matrix 1, and inserting it into the'
'first yellow cell found. So I just selected an absolute range and I don'T'
'know how to integrate a search function or another condition or else into the place here!'



cell.Offset(0, -1).Copy Range("k17")


End If
Next

'here I am in the second matrix'
 For Each cell In Range("k1:L10")

'another if'

If cell.Value > "0" Then

'I selected a value in Matrix one, so the cell value in this Matrix'
'is the one of the still active cell'
'but the active cell always is empty'

  cell.Value = ActiveCell.Value
End If
Next


Loop While z > 0

End Sub
```

This code has not the ranges displayed in the Picture, but otherwise applicable.

Comment: What if the first yellow cell is non-empty? Or perhaps you are using conditional formatting? And please do post whatever code you have if you want people to help. SO is not a free code-writing service you know...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Julian. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to subtract 1 from the first value found in Matrix2 but then you don't do anything with that value? or do you mean subtract the cell range so that you can get the text 'Task1'? Also, like the others said, if you post your code, we can help you fix the problem

Comment: @ zac and others. I substract, because the value is a representative of the time. So once the text field is copied into the yellow field, it's like the "Task" is filling one hour of my calendar. So I reduce the value by one, because instead of e.g. 4 (hours) there are only 3 (hours) still to be scheduled into my calendar. This is repeated until my value reaches 0, which is when all 4 hours are placed into my calendar and thus the Task, e.g. cleaning the house, is finished and Excel moves one cell down to the next value, like 5, (hours) and does the same, until all the Tasks are in my calendar.

Comment: @miqi180 I AM using conditionals indeed. I was just not sure how to connect them. If the cell is yellow it's okay to paste my text. But there are two conditionals. If the cell in Matrix one is greater than 0, go to the left and copy it and paste it into a cell in Matrix two IF that cell is yellow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach:

Have a main loop to check each cell in Matrix1. Immediately within the main loop, have a second loop to check if current cell value is '0'. If its not, get the value, subtract it by 1 and reset the cell value. Within the second loop, get your text (as you are doing but I would assign the text to a variable rather than using 'Copy'). Now have a third loop within your second loop to go through Matrix1. Find the first cell with yellow background color (you can use '`cell.interior.color`' to get the color). Change the value to the text you captured earlier in the second loop. You will need a check to make sure you have not run out of 'yellow colored' cells. if this happens, have a flag to exit out of the loops.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds good. What Kind of Loop do you mean? cell(i,j) or For each cell in range("a1:h15") or an if then Statement.

Comment: For Matrix1, do a full range loop (i.e. For Each oCell In Range("A1:H15")). You might need to tweak it if it doesn't perform the search the way you need it (i.e. do the search based on columns and then increment the row. but only if the 'FOR' loop doesn't preform that way you need it to). Also, please don't forget to accept the answer if it helps